# setTimeout in a loop and pass variables to use later

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function func() {
    var totalWidths = 0;
    for( var i = 0, count = arr.length; i < count; i++ ) {
        var image = arr[i];

        insertElemInDOM(image);

        preloadImage(image,function(){
            var w = image.width();
            totalWidths += w;
        });

    }
    // do something with the variable "totalWidths"
    doSomething(totalWidths)
}
```

I have 2 problems here. The image will be always the same (first problem), which one can solve with an anonymous function:

```
    for(...) {
        (function(image) {
            preload(image,function() {
                // now image is the correct one
            });
        })(image);
    }
```

But how do I manage the totalWidths variable in order to use it later on doSomething(totalWidths)? The previous code would have a value of 0 for totalWidths.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this timer in the first place?

Comment: @Diodeus: I am guessing the DOM element is not present when the code is executed. Therefore, checking for element´s width has to be delayed.

Comment: That's true! That's exactly the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could timeout the whole loop and the `doSomething`, that's much more performant than setting up so many timeouts:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var inc = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var w = arr[i].width();
        inc++;
    }
    doSomething(inc);
}, 1000);
```

---

However, what you actually seem to want are nested timeouts, i.e. waiting 1s for each iteration step and doing something after all have finished:

```
var inc = 0, count;
function asyncLoop(i, callback) {
    if (i < count) {
        var w = arr[i].width();
        inc++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            asyncLoop(i+1, callback);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
asyncLoop(0, function() {
    doSomething(inc);
});
```

---

OK, now that we know what you need the solution is to check after each load event whether all images are loaded:

```
var totalWidths = 0,
    count = arr.length,
    loaded = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    (function (image) {
        insertElemInDOM(image);
        preload(image, function() {
            totalWidths += image.width();
            // counter:
            loaded++;
            if (loaded == count-1) // the expected value
                doSomething(totalWidths); // call back
        });
    })(arr[i]);
```

Comment: I need to setTimeout for another reason just for getting the element's width.

Comment: Use `load` event instead if  this is a loading nodes issue

Comment: To be more precise: This code is just a simple example. The real problem I am facing is that I am inserting an element/image in the DOM, and the setTimeout(in my case the image preload function) is used  to calculate the width of the image after is preloaded. I hope this makes sense.. :S

Comment: So this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). @Jonas You should have stated that in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @Jonas However you can't do that because image doesn't have size until loaded so you go for preload and then wait for load with some questionable code instead of using the right event in the first place